# bash script for creating multiple files using forloop

Tags: bash

I am brand new at `bash` script. I want to write a script using forloop which will give me the following line and execute also these lines.

```
gmx trjconv -f md_0_1.xtc -s md_0_1.tpr -b 1000 -e 10000 -skip 10 -o 1.out
gmx trjconv -f md_0_1.xtc -s md_0_1.tpr -b 2000 -e 20000 -skip 10 -o 2.out
gmx trjconv -f md_0_1.xtc -s md_0_1.tpr -b 3000 -e 30000 -skip 10 -o 3.out
gmx trjconv -f md_0_1.xtc -s md_0_1.tpr -b 4000 -e 40000 -skip 10 -o 4.out
gmx trjconv -f md_0_1.xtc -s md_0_1.tpr -b 5000 -e 50000 -skip 10 -o 5.out
gmx trjconv -f md_0_1.xtc -s md_0_1.tpr -b 6000 -e 60000 -skip 10 -o 6.out
gmx trjconv -f md_0_1.xtc -s md_0_1.tpr -b 7000 -e 70000 -skip 10 -o 7.out
```

....

Comment: Your question ins't really clear. Do you want a different script to execute each command and call that from within another script? Please clarify.

Comment: I want the script that will create the that command and execute that command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also save a couple of lines of typing and get them all done in parallel with **GNU Parallel**:

```
parallel gmx trjconv -f md_0_1.xtc -s md_0_1.tpr -b {}000 -e {}0000 -skip 10 -o {}.out ::: {1..7}
```

Use `parallel --dry-run` if you want to see what it would do but without actually doing anything.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You know it makes sense - especially as CPUs continue to get wider (more cores) rather than taller (more GHz).... :-)

Comment: Very nice command! `parallel` isn't shipped with Ubuntu though

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin May I suggest spending an hour on `man parallel_tutorial`?

Comment: Yes, will do. I can see it being beneficial in large builds for those packages that can be built in parallel (peripheral packages, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Using a basic bash for loop:

```
for i in {1..7}; do
  gmx trjconv -f md_0_1.xtc -s md_0_1.tpr -b ${i}000 -e ${i}0000 -skip 10 -o $i.out
done
```

Comment: You need to multiply your `-b` and `-e` values by `$i`. (e.g. `-b $((i * 1000))`)

Comment: I didn't see that, thanks @DavidC.Rankin. You don't have to multiply though, `${i}000` does the trick :)

Comment: Sure, that's another creative way to solve the problem. I'll give you a vote on that one `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a C-style loop as well, e.g.

```
for ((i = 1; i < 8; i++)); do
    echo "gmx trjconv -f md_0_1.xtc -s md_0_1.tpr -b $((i * 1000)) -e $((i * 10000)) -skip 10 -o $i.out"
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ for ((i = 1; i < 8; i++)); do
>     echo "gmx trjconv -f md_0_1.xtc -s md_0_1.tpr -b $((i * 1000)) -e $((i * 10000)) -skip 10 -o $i.out"
> done
gmx trjconv -f md_0_1.xtc -s md_0_1.tpr -b 1000 -e 10000 -skip 10 -o 1.out
gmx trjconv -f md_0_1.xtc -s md_0_1.tpr -b 2000 -e 20000 -skip 10 -o 2.out
gmx trjconv -f md_0_1.xtc -s md_0_1.tpr -b 3000 -e 30000 -skip 10 -o 3.out
gmx trjconv -f md_0_1.xtc -s md_0_1.tpr -b 4000 -e 40000 -skip 10 -o 4.out
gmx trjconv -f md_0_1.xtc -s md_0_1.tpr -b 5000 -e 50000 -skip 10 -o 5.out
gmx trjconv -f md_0_1.xtc -s md_0_1.tpr -b 6000 -e 60000 -skip 10 -o 6.out
gmx trjconv -f md_0_1.xtc -s md_0_1.tpr -b 7000 -e 70000 -skip 10 -o 7.out
```

Comment: Dear Sir, it gives me the Syntax error: Bad for loop variable

Comment: Hmm, are you using `i` somewhere else as a variable? That's the only thing I can think of. Obviously `i` is not a *Bad for loop variable*... Make sure you have no typo. (you can just copy/paste the code right into an xterm to run it -- it works -- no error... (make sure you copy the top code without the `>` (those are just terminal line continuation marks (actually your PS3 prompt) that the terminal outputs when entering multi-line input)